# Function composition chain rule problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm really stuck on this one:

Let $ f:R^2\rightarrow R \in C^1,   g: R^+\rightarrow R$ s.t.
$g(t)=f(cost/t,sint/t) $

Assume $ g'(t)>0 $. Prove $ \nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$.

My intuition was to derive the function using the chain rule, but I'm having a hard time inferring anything. Another thought is maybe to use a series of numbers such as $ t_n=2\pi k+\theta $ where $g(t)\rightarrow f(0,0) $.

I still can't see how I can get to the conclusion, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)$ be the standard coordinate function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Using the chain rule, we calculate the derivative of the composition.

\begin{align*}g'(t) &= f'\left(\frac{\cos t}{t}, \frac{\sin t}{t} \right) \cdot - \left(\frac{t \sin t + \cos t}{t^2},\frac{\sin t- t \cos t}{t^2}\right)\\ \\ &= \begin{pmatrix} f_x & f_y \end{pmatrix}\Bigr|_{\left(\frac{\cos t}{t}, \frac{\sin t}{t} \right):= \alpha(t)} \cdot- \left(\frac{t \sin t + \cos t}{t^2},\frac{\sin t- t \cos t}{t^2}\right) >0\end{align*}

The evaluation at $(0,0)$ corresponds to $t = \pi/2 + \pi k$. If we plus this into $\alpha(t)$ then we have the following,

$$ \pm \bigg( \underbrace{f_x(0,0) \cdot  \left( \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k\right) + f_y(0,0)}_{:= \lambda(k)}\bigg) <0 $$

If $k$ is odd then we have $\lambda(k) <0$ and so there is no way that the gradient$\nabla f(0,0) = (0,0)$ since this would imply $\lambda(k) = 0$. Is there something in the proposition that you are overlooking?